# Parse HTML using Python

Tags: python, html, beautifulsoup, html-parsing

I am trying to parse HTML using Beautiful SOAP (Python Library). Does anyone know how to parse below HTML using Beautiful SOAP?

```
  <span class="passingAlert bar">
     <span class="fold-buttons">
         <a href="#" onclick="fold();">Fold</a> | 
         <a href="#" onclick="unfold();">Unfold</a>
     </span>149 specs, 0 failed, 0 pending
  </span>
```

I need to get 149 specs, 0 failed, 0 pending from HTML.

Comment: to parse you need `soup = BeautifulSoap(your_html, 'html.parser')`. After that you have to only "search".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
html = '''<span class="passingAlert bar">
     <span class="fold-buttons">
         <a href="#" onclick="fold();">Fold</a> | 
         <a href="#" onclick="unfold();">Unfold</a>
     </span>149 specs, 0 failed, 0 pending
  </span>'''

from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'html.parser')

# get <span class="fold-buttons">
c = soup.find(class_="fold-buttons")

# get element after `span`
print( c.nextSibling.strip() )
```